# Is it possible to use the DELIMITER statement when using the DISPLAY statement

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Let's say I wanted to do a FOR EACH of 3 tables/fields:

`slmast.name`
`slmast.acode`
`slmast.address.`

Usually, they are presented neatly with nothing separating them.

However, would I also be able to use the DELIMITER statement to separate them, or add commas/ speech marks?

For example:

```
 FOR EACH slmast.

 DISPLAY (DELIMITER) "," slmast.name slmast.acode slmast.address
```

Comment: The reason people are guessing in their answers is that you do not mention WHY you want a different delimiter between them. Since you mention comma and speech marks, it sounds like you want to export your data as a CSV, in which the export statement with delimiter option would make much more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, DELIMITER is not an option for DISPLAY.

You could do as Mike suggests and build a string with SUBSTITUTE or you could add the desired commas like so:

```
for each slmast no-lock:

  display 
    name + "," format "x(30)"
    acode + ","
    address + "," format "x(30)"
  .

end.
```

This will make nice columns if that's what you want whereas Mike's code will eliminate spaces - which, alternatively, might be what you want.

You need the FORMAT phrase if the width will exceed the default format of 8. I left acode unadorned to show the default.

Comment: As Tom says, the how you do this depends on where the output is (screen, file), and what the expected format is.
You might also look into the PUT statement, with or without an UNFORMATTED option.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the SUBSTITUTE() function:

```
FOR EACH slmast NO-LOCK:

  DISPLAY
    SUBSTITUTE ("&1,&2,&3", slmast.name, slmast.acode, slmast.address) FORMAT "x(60)"
  .

END.
```